# How do I prevent Ouibounce from appearing on Mobile?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

I've implemented [Ouibounce](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce) and it works amazing.
Below is the sample scripted code.

My question is how do I prevent the popup from launching on mobile?
My first solution was to give the modal div a display:none value when under 479px but I am certain there is a smarter solution...

Thanks

```
<script>        
        var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
            aggressive: true,
            timer: 0,
            callback: function () { console.log('ouibounce fired!'); }
        });
        $('body').on('click', function () {
            $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
        });
        $('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function () {
            $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
        });
        $('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the late response. Just found this after searching for something similar myself. The below should work for you.

```js
function() {
  // detect mobile device
  var mobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile|webOS/i);

  if (mobile) {
    return mobile;
  } else {
    return "desktop";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ouibounce doesn't ever fire on mobile, by design. It tracks cursor movement and there isn't any on touchscreens.